# Symfony 3.4 AuthorizationChecker not available

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am dealing with some old symfony code, and I have a bundle that needs AuthorizationCheckerInterface. I can see that symfony/security-core is installed but if I check the container I don't see the service:

```
app/console debug:container | grep "checker"
```

does not return anything. Is there a way to expose this service? I just need a basic configuration to make the command above return **security.authorization_checker** and satisfy those dependencies.

Comment: Try without the quotes `bin/console debug:container checker`. You should get a list of services.  If not then are your sure the security bundle is installed?  You need the bundle not just the core.  And I am not positive but you probably need the authorization system configured as well.

Comment: My understandind was that the security bundle is part of the symfony core and doesn't need to be installed separately, but maybe I am wrong. I think it is as I can see the package inside the vendor folder. I thougth I need to setup a basic config yml file in some way to make the service available. As said, it is just for a dependency, I don't really need to use it.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  security-core is just a library that could (in theory) be used outside of the framework.  The bundle is required and is responsible for defining services.  And when you think about, isGranted makes no sense unless you first have an authenticated user.  If you are not going to actually use the checker then you could define your own service that always just returns true or false.

Comment: I agree with @Cerad's last statement. If this is truly a service that has no value to you, I wouldn't bother adding a bunch of complexity from bundles, just make a service and register it with that alias. You might even want to `throw` instead of returning something just to see how whatever is requiring it is actually using it.

Comment: that's not so simple unfortunatelly. I have a bundle that is shared with another symfony installation, where that service is active, and the bundle uses it. On this other symfony installation that bundle was never updated. Now I am updating it as I need another functionality from it and it is triggering an error because of this missing service. I understand that is probably not well architected but for many reasons I am not going to refactor this piece of code, I'd prefer the dirty way of just make the service available if possible. If you know a way I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `class MyAuthorizationChecker implements AuthorizationCheckerInterface ...`. Have isGranted toss an exception and make a service definition.  The conditional thing might be a bit confusing.  You could use a compiler pass to check if the service already exists and, if not, define your fake service.